# str.replace does not replace char

Tags: java, string, replace

Im a beginner to java and trying to build my own weather app.
When getting the temperature, the output is

```
/?4°
```

or

```
/?-4°
```

Now I only need to get the temperature (4° or -4°). How can I achieve this?
I already tried

```
str.replace('?',' ')
```

But that does nothing. My problem with

```
str.replaceAll('\\D', ' ')
```

is, that it also removes the - sign. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Strings in java are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed. The method `str.replace('?',' ')` returns a new String where the characters are replaced.

Comment: Please read the `replace` docs, e.g., old but valid, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak your regex and use:

```
str = str.replaceAll('[^\\d-]', '')
```

This will replace all non digits nor hyphens.

Beware that you need to assign the result of `str.replaceAll`

Comment: It'd be good to address what the original issue was tho

Comment: Well your original post did not contain the underlying issue, which I see you added now `Beware that you need to assign the result of str.replaceAll`